# PHP natcasesort giving booleon error

Tags: php, foreach, count

I have been trying to read the errors and figure out the solution for a while now, I can't seem to get it.

In short, the code below grabs a numbered list of php files that displays the events. However, when there are no php files in this directory, it displays the text, Sorry, No upcoming events.

```
$events = glob("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/events/shot/*.php");

if(count($events)) {
natcasesort($events);

$i=0;
foreach($events as $event) {
if($i > 3) {
    break;
}
$event = basename($event);
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/events/shot/$event");
$i++;
};
    }

else {

echo 'Sorry, no upcoming events.';

}
```

My problem is, when there are no php files in the directory, I get the errors:

```
Warning: natcasesort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home/famili23/public_html/assets/events/shot.php on line 11

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/famili23/public_html/assets/events/shot.php on line 14
```

I cannot quite figure this one out. If someone can help me on this, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob` *may* return `false` on error (I'm not sure which circumstances would constitute an error). `false` cast to an array will be the value `array(false)`, i.e. an array with one entry `false`. `count` casts its argument to an array, so in the event of `glob` returning `false`, `count(false)` will result in `1`. That's why it's entering the condition regardless, and since `$events` is not an array the following functions are complaining.

Since an empty array is equal to `false`, I'd suggest you simply do this:

```
if ($events) ...
```

This is true if and only if `glob` returned an array with at least one element, and false in all other cases including empty arrays and `false`.

Comment: `false` can indicate an empty result too, as *On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.* http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: @pozs Yeah, it says *"an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error"*, followed by that vague statement. So I'm still not quite sure what exactly that means... ;)

Comment: sure, that's why I wrote it *can* indicate an empty result too. Another possibility is an erroneous pattern, such as `foo[name*.php`, but the OP's problem only exists when there is no file in that directory, so I would guess the former one applies here.

Comment: Simple.. the `count` was throwing the script off and returning a `false` when no files present. Simply removing the `count()` has resolved my issue and I understand why. Thank you for your help!